# Разбить строку по нескольким разделителям

Tags: javascript

Нужно разбить строку по нескольким разделителям ("?" и "&"). Код пишу такой:

```
res = '1?2'.split('/[\?|\&]/');
```

Но почему-то не хочет работать. Что не так?

Answer (score 3):

Кавычки уберите, & - не является спец символом поэтому не экранирутся и квадратные скобки не нужны.

```
res = '1?2&3'.split(/\?|&/);
```

Answer (score -1):

В случае, когда RegExp создается динамически, с использованием строкового шаблона (`${}`), необходимо пропускать полученную переменную через

```
const regexps = markers.map((elem) => `${elem}.*`).join('|');
input.split(new RegExp(regexps))
```